# How to make AWS beanstalk enviroment run faster

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I uploaded a asp.net framework MVC web app page to AWS beanstalk and it works extreamly slow.

How can i make the enviroment run faster?

These are my current configurations:

[image]

Is it a problem that when I published the web app to aws it was in debug and not release?.

I tried upsizing the instance but i get this error:

[image]

Comment: Upsize your instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the requests I made to the client to get their mac address to authorize them.Since I did that for every action it made the web app very slow.